# 遠隔地からのssh接続方法がつかめない(東京→京都)

Tags: linux, ssh

#### 前置き

5月に持病の治療の為、上京する運びとなりまして、不要となったノートPCを自分専用の多用途サーバーに換装する作業を進めています。丁度スマートフォンの空き容量が画像ファイルで押しつぶされそうになっているので、一旦PCに取り込んで`ssh`で多用途サーバーに送信しようかと考えていますが、ここで技術的な課題に直面しました。

#### 東京から自宅のある京都までどのようにして接続するのか？

これに関してはサーバーサイドが苦手な性格が災いして、調べてみてもよくわかりませんでした（というよりもネットワーク関係の抽象的な構図が苦手）。何度かsshで自分のスマートフォンに接続した経験はありますが、遠隔地からの接続は今まで想定していなかったので、全く理解が及ばずといった形です。

兎にも角にも5月までには完成させなければいけないので、お力添えのほど、よろしくおねがいします。
これといった情報量もなく、淡白な文章で申し訳ありません。ただ、自分の技術力では、どのような構図にしたいかすら説明できないレベルですので、どうかご容赦願いたいと思います。

ご不明な点があればコメントにて全力で回答します。どうかよろしくおねがいします。

p.s　なぜかタグ追加ができないので（サーバーと打とうとしても、"さ"を打った時点で"あ"に変換される）そこのところもご理解の程お願いします。

#### ある程度まとまって来たので追記

宿泊先のLANから、自宅のLAN内のサーバーに接続するにはWANを通す必要があり、そこにはルーターが鍵を握っていることがわかりました。以下わからない事を書いていきます

#### ルーターの設定

私はeo光ユーザーでルーターは`eoRT-100`を使っています。そこで本機の`DHCP固定割当設定`で`wlp2s0f0`のアドレス(MACアドレスも含む)を設定。そしてポートマッピング[1](https://support.eonet.jp/connect/net/multi_bbr/eo-rt100/fun/adv_net_portmap.html)には、先程のアドレスとポート番号`2222`を設定しました。さて、ここまで設定すれば、グローバルアドレスをnmapで調べても当然サーバーと限定的に紐付いている筈なので、`2222`番ポートの検出を期待しましたが、それはなされませんでした。これは一体何を指し示しているのでしょうか？また、何をどうすべきなのでしょうか？

これをネットワーク構成と言うのかは定かではありませんが、サーバー側のipコマンドの出力ログを貼っておきます。

```
kyoto-sigma% ip link show && ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:50:e6:3a:51:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:77:e6:2b:c7:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:50:e6:3a:51:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:77:e6:2b:c7:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.11/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0f0
       valid_lft 82177sec preferred_lft 82177sec
    inet6 2001:ce8:132:b7b4:8719:83bd:f2d3:56af/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 219sec preferred_lft 219sec
    inet6 fe80::dba1:92cb:91ab:386a/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: 個人的な事情よりも、まずは質問内容にフォーカスして内容を投稿しましょう。結局、クライアントとサーバがそれぞれ何であって、どんな方法を試したのかが現状では読み取れません。

Comment: とんだご無礼をお許し下さい。少々混乱していました。ますサーバー機ですが、これは5年前に購入したラップトップです。メモリは4GiBでストレージが500GiBです。そして遠方の東京から`ssh`により`ローカルなLAN内`ではなく`宿泊先のLAN内のPC(ThinkPadX280)`から自宅にあるサーバー機へsshによるアクセス全般を行いたいと考えています。その為、LANを跨いだアクセス方法、及びセッティングが思うように掴めず、難儀している状態です。

Comment: 東京や京都といった地理情報はこの質問に必要なのでしょうか？ 逆にLANを跨いだアクセス方法に難儀しているなら、そのネットワーク構成を説明しないのはなぜですか？

Comment: すみません。ネットワーク構成に関してはズブの素人なので、どこから説明していけばよいかわからない状況です。`ip`や`ifconfig`で調べられる情報のことを指しているのか？それとも`単にネットワーク図`を指しているのかすらもわからない状態です。本当にすみません。できればもう少し程お手柔らかにお願いします。本当にごめんなさい

Comment: 距離が離れていようとネットワーク的に繋がっており、かつアクセス許可さえあれば通常は問題無いはずですよね？ / 恐らく今回やりたい事としては、アクセス先の端末は社内等のLAN環境にあって、アクセス元は全く関係のないLANの外からアクセスしたい、ということではないでしょうか。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて見直してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ざっくりとした概要のみを回答しますので、詳細はキーワードを頼りにご自身で調べて頂くか
別途質問を行ってみてください。

- 固定IPを割り当てる
  個人で契約している回線の場合、大抵は動的IPアドレスが割り当てられており、ルータの再起動等のタイミングでIPアドレスが変わってしまいます。

  プロバイダが用意している「固定IPのサービスを利用する」

  [eo 固定アドレスサービス、ドメイン取得サービス](https://eonet.jp/option/other/ipaddress/)

  もしくは「ダイナミックDNS」で固定のドメイン名でアクセスできるようにする方法が考えられます。

  [DDNS（ダイナミックDNS）とは - IT用語辞典 e-Words](http://e-words.jp/w/DDNS.html)
- ルータでローカルIPにポートマッピングを行う
  ルータのWAN側アドレスに対するアクセスを、LAN内のプライベートアドレスに通すために「ポートマッピング」を行います。
- サーバPCでsshdの設定を行う
  当然ながら、アクセス先のPCにてsshdの設定を行っておく必要があります。

Comment: どうも`eoRT-100`の使用上ローカル内のアクセスでは、リモートホストからの接続は受け付けないようです。試しにテザリング機能を使ってアクセスしてみた所無事接続できました。無料のDDNSもあったので試しにリモートホストを登録してみた所ズムーズにサーバー構築が完了しました。ご協力に感謝します

Answer (score 0):

1. 自宅の回線は何でしょうか。光回線などのグローバルIPからアクセスできる回線でないとそもそも無理な話となります。
   光回線でも、マンションタイプなどは、大本でルータが挟まるため、外部からのアクセスができません
2. サーバマシンのSSH設定はきちんと行えてるでしょうか。
   LAN内から、ローカルIPで接続して確認する必要があります
3. あなたんちのルータの設定で、ポートフォワーディング設定を行う必要があります

と以上の条件、設定、を満たした上で、あなたんちのグローバルIPで、ポートフォワーディングしたポート番号でアクセスできるようになる、はずです